# How to fetch a query from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm connected to the database but I cannot get the query to print. I did it on phpMyAdmin and it works, have table profiles and table request they both have the right relations, now when I try to execute on PHP it doesn't print anything.

```
<?php
include 'mydb.php';

$data = mysql_query("select amount,name from request, profiles where request.profiles_id = profiles.id and request.profiles_id = 23")  or die(mysql_error());

Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";  

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{ 
     Print "<tr>"; 
     Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['name'] . "</td> ";  
     Print "<th>amount:</th> <td>".$info['amount'] . " </td></tr>";  
}  
Print "</table>";  
?>
```

How can I get it to print the info that works on phpMyAdmin console? I'm new to this and this is the farthest I can reach so far.

Comment: can i edit add an answer but not with mysql but with PDO ? cause mysql is to old not and MYSQLI and PDO are better and more improved than mysql it self

Comment: It looks like it should work. Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the script so you'll get warnings if there's a problem in your script.

Comment: Are you getting an empty table?

Comment: it works now i had an open tag, last thing, i set 23 which is the id from the user i have several user and they a logged in by session, how is the best way to replace 23 for the user logged id